# Docker compose + Wordpress Bedrock too many redirects issue

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose, roots-toolkit

I am having issues getting a bedrock site up and running on Docker with `docker-compose`. I have a minimal setup using the wordpress image with mariadb. Everything spins up fine, and I am able to go through the install and access the admin, but the site won't load. (too many redirects)

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/html
      - ./config:/var/www/config
      - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor
      - ./.env:/var/www/.env
      - ./composer.json:/var/www/composer.json
      - ./wp-cli.yml:/var/www/wp-cli.yml
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

and here is my .env file:

```
DB_NAME='wordpress'
DB_USER='wordpress'
DB_PASSWORD='wordpress'

# Optionally, you can use a data source name (DSN)
# When using a DSN, you can remove the DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, and DB_HOST variables
# DATABASE_URL='mysql://wordpress:wordpress@db:3306/wordpress'

# Optional database variables
DB_HOST='db:3306'
# DB_PREFIX='wp_'

WP_ENV='development'
WP_HOME='http://localhost:80'
WP_SITEURL="${WP_HOME}/wp"

# Specify optional debug.log path
# WP_DEBUG_LOG='/path/to/debug.log'

# Generate your keys here: https://roots.io/salts.html
AUTH_KEY='redacted'
SECURE_AUTH_KEY='redacted'
LOGGED_IN_KEY='redacted'
NONCE_KEY='redacted'
AUTH_SALT='redacted'
SECURE_AUTH_SALT='redacted'
LOGGED_IN_SALT='redacted'
NONCE_SALT='redacted'
```

EDIT: Also worth pointing out that wordpress can't locate the theme directory